# How to send byte message to ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a method for sending a message via JMS, but I don't understand why I don't change the message type.

```
public static void sendMessage(QueueSession queueSession, MessageProducer messageProducer, String body, long expiration, String replyTo, int persistent, int priority, Map<String, String> propertiesMap, String CorrelationID, String typeMessage) {
    try {
        if (messageProducer == null){
            DialogsAlert.queueConnectionError.showAndWait();
        }
        Queue replyToQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + replyTo);
        messageProducer.setPriority(priority);
        messageProducer.setTimeToLive(expiration);
        messageProducer.setDeliveryMode(persistent);
        TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(body);
        message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToQueue);
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(CorrelationID);
        message.setJMSType(typeMessage);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
            if (!property.getKey().isEmpty()) {
                message.setStringProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
            }
        }
        messageProducer.send(message);
        DialogsAlert.messageSendSuccess.showAndWait();
    } catch (JMSException | NamingException e) {
        DialogsAlert.messageSendError.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

I specified the values: 3, 4, text, byte in the typeMessage field. I want the message type to be byte, but in the Artemis queue it is always text. I don't understand why it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the type to be `4` (i.e. bytes) then you need to send an actual JMS `BytesMessage`, e.g.:

```java
public static void sendMessage(QueueSession queueSession, MessageProducer messageProducer, String body, long expiration, String replyTo, int persistent, int priority, Map<String, String> propertiesMap, String CorrelationID, String typeMessage) {
    try {
         if (messageProducer == null){
            DialogsAlert.queueConnectionError.showAndWait();
         }
         Queue replyToQueue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + replyTo);
         messageProducer.setPriority(priority);
         messageProducer.setTimeToLive(expiration);
         messageProducer.setDeliveryMode(persistent);
         BytesMessage message = queueSession.createBytesMessage();
         message.writeBytes(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToQueue);
         message.setJMSCorrelationID(CorrelationID);
         message.setJMSType(typeMessage);
         for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
            if (!property.getKey().isEmpty()) {
               message.setStringProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
            }
         }
         messageProducer.send(message);
         DialogsAlert.messageSendSuccess.showAndWait();
      } catch (JMSException | NamingException e) {
         DialogsAlert.messageSendError.showAndWait();
      }
   }
}
```

The value set using [`setJMSType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSType-java.lang.String-) is really a provider-specific value. It doesn't reflect the underlying data structure of the message which is what "type" refers to when looking at the web console. JMS supports the following kinds of messages:

- [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html)
- [Bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html)
- [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html)
- [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html) (not recommended)
- [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/StreamMessage.html)